# Check my proof: Strong induction by weak induction

Tags: logic, solution-verification, proof-writing, induction

Many proofs have been posted here, but I'm not confident that I see through them well enough such that I'm really sure that my proof is correct. Thankful for any feedback, including nitpicking.

Some clarifications: n++ means the successor function, i.e. n++ = n+1. I hope the propositions / lemmas etc. I refer to in the proof are obvious enough that it doesn't hinder understanding drastically.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please do not rely on images to convey information not otherwise present in your post. [See here for an explanation](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742). In my case, your image is almost unreadable in my display.

Comment: Thank you for the link, I was not aware of this. I'll try to redo this post using MathJax.

Comment: MathJax is similar to LaTeX, so if you have your proof done in LaTeX you can paste it here.